# Need help implementing react-hook-form with Gatsby.js: form won't even post values to console

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I have this form in Gatsby.js that loads components for it's inputs - input text, textarea, dropdown etc. These components were not entirely dumb since their classes should change on focus, click or hover, so I had some sort of function to make it work.

However, it wasn't that great (I'm a front-end guy trying to do my best here) and after some research I found out about react-hook-form that could not only handle that logic behind the components (with formState.touch and formState.isDirty ) but do the validations for me. Sounded like a plan.

So I've stripped off these components of their logic so they would be simpler and am trying to use it on that form. But I can't even post the fields values to the console, meaning I'm going the wrong approach. I believe I'm not registering the components properly, having tried many ways to do it already.

I'd appreciate any help letting me understand what's wrong with this approach and what could I do to make it work. This thing is killing me for days now.

**UPDATE**: *after a little studying I have managed to make it work partially - the text inputs at least. I will answer this question so I can make another one regarding the remaining problem.*

Here's the code I have now for the components

**Input.js**

```
// Input.js - from where <Input> and <TextArea> components come from
import React from "react";

import "../../sass/components/forms/input.sass"

export function Input({ className, label, name, onChange, value, register, required, type }) {
  
  return (
    <div 
      className={`inputContainer ${className}`}>
      <div
        className={`
        inputHeader 
        `}>
        <span className="inputLabel" >{label}</span>
        <input 
          id={name}
          className="field"
          onChange={onChange} 
          value={value}
          ref={register({ required })}
          type={type}/>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
  

export function TextArea({ className, label, name, onChange, value, register, required, type }) {

  return (
    <div 
      className={`
      textAreaContainer ${className}
      `}>
      <span className="textAreaLabel">{label}</span>
      <textarea 
        id={name}
        className="field" 
        onChange={onChange} 
        ref={register({ required })}
        type={type} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

**Dropdown.js**

```
// Dropdown.js - from where <Dropdown> comes. Notice that it's not a <select> tag but a list with containers around. That was the only way I was able to customize it the way we need it.

import React, { useState } from "react";
import "../../sass/components/forms/dropdown.sass"


export function Dropdown(props) {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(null);
    
  const toggling = () => setIsOpen(!isOpen);

  const onOptionClicked = value => () => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
    setIsOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <div className="dropdownContainer">
      <span>{props.preambulo}</span>
      <div 
        className={`
          dropdownHeader 
          ${isOpen === true ? 'open' : 'closed'} 
          `} 
          onClick={toggling}
          >
        {selectedOption || props.placeholder}
      </div>
      {isOpen && (
        <div 
          className="dropdownListContainer">
            <ul 
              className="dropdownList"
              ref={props.ref}
              name={props.name}
              id={props.name}
              >
              {props.options.map((option, i) => (
                <li 
                  className={`dropdownListItem item-${i}`} 
                  key={i} 
                  onClick={onOptionClicked(option)}>
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
              <hr />
            </ul>
        </div>
        )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

And then the form.

**contatoFull.js**

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

//Form Components
import { Dropdown } from "../../components/forms/Dropdown"
import { Input, TextArea } from "../../components/forms/Input"

const ContatoFull = ({ className }) => {
 
  const cargos = [
    "Chefe",
    "Diretor",
    "Gerente",
    "Funcionário",
    "Outros"
  ]

  const estados = [
    "Acre",
    "Alagoas",
    "Amazonas",
    "Amapá",
    "Bahia",
    "Ceará",
    "Distrito Federal",
    "Espírito Santo",
    "Goiás",
    "Maranhão",
    "Minas Gerais",
    "Mato Grosso do Sul",
    "Mato Grosso",
    "Pará",
    "Paraíba",
    "Pernambuco",
    "Piauí",
    "Paraná",
    "Rio de Janeiro",
    "Rio Grande do Norte",
    "Rondônia",
    "Roraima",
    "Rio Grande do Sul",
    "Santa Catarina",
    "Sergipe",
    "São Paulo",
    "Tocantins"
  ]
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form 
      method="post"
      className={`${className !== 0 ? className : ''}`} 
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>

      <Dropdown 
        options={cargos}
        ref={register} 
        className="cargo dropdown" 
        preambulo="Eu sou" 
        placeholder="Tomador(a) de decisão" />

      <Dropdown 
        options={estados}
        ref={register} 
        className="estado dropdown" 
        preambulo="Estou no" 
        placeholder="Acre" />

      <Input 
        register={register}
        required
        className="empresa" 
        label="Nome da minha empresa" 
        type="text " />
        
      
      <Input 
        register={register}
        required
        className="primeiro nome" 
        label="Nome" 
        type="text" />
      <Input 
        register={register}
        required
        className="segundo nome" 
        label="Sobrenome" 
        type="text" />
      <Input 
        register={register({
          required: true, 
          pattern: /^\S+@\S+$/i
        })}
        required
        className="email" 
        label="E-mail de contato" 
        type="email" 
        />
        
      <Input
        register={register({
          required: true, minLength: 6, maxLength: 12
        })}
        required
        className="telefone" 
        label="Telefone de contato" 
        type="tel" />

      <TextArea
        register={register}
        required
        className="mensagem" 
        label="Escreva sua mensagem"/>

      <button 
        type="submit" 
        className="simpleButton primary submit button">Enviar</button>
    </form>
  )
}

export default ContatoFull
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue with the code in this question is the registration of those fields, `<Input>`, `<TextArea>` and `<Dropdown>`. The manner I was using, passing props `register` to the components, was wrong.

Using `<Controller>` to make the registration of the fields worked out properly after some work. Here it is what I've done:

```
import { useForm, Controler } from 'react-hook-form' 

const ContatoForm = () => {

  (...)

  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);

  return (
    <form 
      method="post"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="firstName"
        render={props =>
          <Input
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            label="label here"
            value={value}
            onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
        }
      />
    </form>
  )
}
```

The code for the text components `<input>` were basically a wrapper `inputContainer` for `inputHeader`, `inputLabel` and the input itself `field`:

```
//** Component structure
   <div 
      className={`inputContainer ${className}`}>
      <div
        className={`
        inputHeader 
        `}>
        <span className="inputLabel" >{label}</span>
        <input 
          id={name}
          className="field"
          onChange={onChange} 
          value={value}
          ref={register({ required })}
          type={type}/>
      </div>
    </div>
```

However, applying validation for required fields, for instance, would place the errors outside this structure. Something like this:

```
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="firstName"
        render={props =>
          <Input
            name="firstName"
            type="text"
            label="label here"
            value={value}
            onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
        }
      />
      {errors.firstName && <span>Field is required</span>}
```

Nothing wrong with that, but for a design choice, I've transferred the container from the component to the parent so it would embrace the displayed error.

```
// New input component
export function Input({ label, name, onChange, value, type }) {
  
  return (
    <div
      className={`
      inputHeader 
      `}>
      <span className="inputLabel" >{label}</span>
      <input 
        id={name}
        className="field"
        onChange={onChange} 
        value={value}
        type={type}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
// New parent 
(...)
  const { handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = data => console.log(data);
  return (
    <div 
      className={`inputContainer firstName`}>
      <Controller 
        name="firstName" 
        label="Name" 
        type="text"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        rules={{ required: true }}
        render={({ onChange, value, name, type, label }) =>
          <Input 
            onChange={e => onChange(e.target.value)}
            value={value}
            label={label} 
            name={name}
            type={type} />
        }
      />
      {errors.firstName && <span className="error">Field is required.</span>}
   )
```

This way I can fetch the input value on submit with proper validation.